# tablesorter js in html (404 not found)

Tags: html, jquery, flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

My folder structure is..

```
home 
   <-lib/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js
   <-templates/index.html
   <-static/styles.css
```

I'm running a flask application and the py script is in the home directory.

I keep getting a "404/NOT FOUND" when the html loads on my browser (Chrome - localhost). I have read through similar threads here and elsewhere, but cannot seem to get this to work (most topic threads were around folder structures).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tablesorter is a jQuery plugin, yes? And as such requires that jQuery is already loaded? Try changing the order of your script tags.

Comment: @JohnPrideaux  yes it is a jquery plugin (am keen on avoiding boilerplate code to sort tables). I've reversed the sequence (i.e., load jquery first and then the tablesorter), but I get the same result - 404. 

   Request URL: http://localhost:5000/lib/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js

Answer (score 0):

The error message was straight-forward....the browser was expecting the file to be served via the flask server, which is not the normal way of doing this. I've used href in the same way as I'd use it to serve static files, and the browser does not complain now.